# VB.NET code re-ordering to interface

Tags: vb.net, code-formatting

Is there a simple way, without using external tools, to get the physical layout of my classes to match my interface?

If I have an interface, `IFoo`:

```
Interface IFoo
    Function DoFoo() As Integer
    Function DoBar() As Integer
End Function
```

I will end up with a class:

```
Class MyFoo
    Public Function DoFoo() As Integer Implements IFoo.DoFoo
        '...
    End Function

    Public Function DoBar() As Integer Implements IFoo.DoBar
        '...
    End Function
End Function
```

I then decide to add `GetFoo()` to my interface. I put it with DoFoo(), since it is a related thing and I want to group like terms. Visual Studio then tells me that the class no longer implements `IFoo` properly. The autogenerated code goes at the end of `MyFoo`.

What I would like to do is either get the item to be inserted in the correct place (under the previous item in the interface), or moved there post-event.

Not had anything very relevant come up using Google.

Comment: It doesn't really matter that much, your function list in the top right of the editor is sorted, so you can always navigate there, and it would do it correctly on a new class implementing this interface, if you want to move it, you can do it by hand.

Comment: True, but more for convenience that GetFoo, DoFoo,UpdateFoo are near each other and GetBar, DoBar are together. The function list would put the Gets and Updates together.

I suppose it was more out of laziness hoping for a Ctrl-K, Ctrl-X to do it for me.

Answer (score 1):

There is not such functionality in Visual Studio. For this, I am using CodeMaid extension, which can arrange VB.NET code alphabetically and by type and scope. It really makes your code beautiful. There is also very good commercial extension called CodeRush for Roslyn which have much more features and it does organizing document little better.